# ValueError in pandas even when using bitwise operators and proper brackets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I am trying to elaborate a df based on some of its columns (col1-4 herein), and to add a new column based on certain conditions defined in a function.
The code might be clearer than an explanation in plain english:

```
def get_new_col(df):
    if (df['col1'] == 0) | (df['col2'] == 0):
        first_half = 0
    else:
        first_half = min(df['col1'], df['col2'])
    if (df['col3'] == 0) | (df['col4'] == 0):
        second_half = 0 
    else:
        second_half = min(df['col3'], df['col4'])
    return first_half + second_half

df['new_col'] = get_new_col(df)
```

My problem is that I am getting a `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`, even though I am properly (I think?) bracketing the conditions of the if statements and using the bitwise operator | instead of `or`, as suggested in this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o).

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need `DataFrame.apply` on rows

```py
def get_new_col(row):
    if (row['col1'] == 0) | (row['col2'] == 0):
        first_half = 0
    else:
        first_half = min(row['col1'], row['col2'])
    if (row['col3'] == 0) | (row['col4'] == 0):
        second_half = 0
    else:
        second_half = min(row['col3'], row['col4'])
    return first_half + second_half

df['new_col'] = df.apply(get_new_col, axis=1)
```

Problem you get is that `df['col1'] == 0` returns a boolean Series which couldn't be accepted by `if` statement.

With `df.apply(get_new_col, axis=1)`, we are only passing one row of dataframe to `get_new_col` function.

To do the same without `apply`, you can try

```py
def get_new_col(df):
    first_half = df[['col1', 'col2']].min(axis=1)
    first_half = first_half.mask(df[['col1', 'col2']].eq(0).any(axis=1), 0)

df['new_col'] = get_new_col(df)
```

Comment: I see, thank you! Would you say that there is a better (read: quicker) way to get to the same result?

Comment: Cool, but why didn't you `return` anything at the end of the function?

Comment: @AntonioCarnevali Just an example, not thoroughly rewrite your original function.